# How to make named entity recognition provide better categorization of data

Tags: nlp, spacy, large-language-model

Following is a default categorization of data from a news article.

```
Christiane Amanpour 268 287 PERSON
Hamas 155 160 ORG
Rania 6 11 PERSON
Warner 0 6 ORG
```

But I would like to change the behavior as follows

```
I would want to categorize `Christiane Amanpour` as a journalist
I would want to categorize `Rania` as a queen
I would want to categorize `Warner` as a cricket player
```

How exactly I train the data to do this

Comment: Have you looked into [entity linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey [@user352290](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352290/user352290)

You're using a Named Entity Recognition (NER) model, which has provided the labels for PERSON and ORG in the example specified (I *think* you're using the default spaCy model?)

Based on your question, it seems you want a more specific categorisation (e.g. Christiane Amanpour -> journalist). Broadly speaking, NER models fall into one of two categories:

- **4-class** models, as the name would suggest, recognise 4 classes of entities. Typically, people, places, organisations, and time/dates. Most 4-class models are trained on the [CoNLL 2003](https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/conll-2003) corpus.
- **18-class** models can recognise 18 entity types, however, they tend to have a lower F1 / accuracy. Most 18-class models are trained on the [OntoNotes 5.0](https://paperswithcode.com/sota/named-entity-recognition-ner-on-ontonotes-v5) dataset.

Even an 18-class NER model *will* fail to categorise entities as you'd like. For example, there's no category for journalist in the OntoNotes corpus.

As [@petezurich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7117003/petezurich) suggests, you can achieve this task via [Entity Linking](https://www.amazon.science/blog/improving-entity-linking-between-texts-and-knowledge-bases), which recognises entities in a text, and maps them to an external source of knowledge (e.g. Wikipedia, DBpedia).

In order to properly implement this, you will have to decide on a "data point" you'd like to locate for each entity. Take a look at the [DBpedia entry for Christiane Amanpour](https://dbpedia.org/page/Christiane_Amanpour). The property [`dbo:occupation`](https://dbpedia.org/page/Christiane_Amanpour__PersonFunction__1) seems to achieve what you're looking for.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/lucafrost/2e4d1e185bf467fe0dabb456c0791d5f) has some code I've previously written to perform NER then Entity Linking. You'll need to make *some* tweaks, but it's a decent place to start. Change line 190 to modify the SPARQL query to fetch `dbo:occupation`, or whichever property you'd like to find.

Good luck!